# HEX Conversion (little-endian)

Tags: hex, radix

I hope someone may be able to help me!

I am trying to work out how the following was done. The Hex below is stored as little-endian:

ff3f fc7f 0040 0000 ffff f17f 0000 0280

I am trying to understand how the author converted (or re-wrote) this to:

7FFC 3FFF 0000 4000 7FF1 FFFF 8002 0000

I have scoured the internet but I am at a loss :(

Thanks in advance for all that can help!

Comment: It looks like the values are 32 bits in this instance, so to swap endianness you need to reverse the order of the 4 bytes in each 32 bit word. So `ff3f fc7f` becomes `7ffc 3fff`, and so on...

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for coming back to me - so is that the first or last 4 bytes? Thanks very much!

Comment: The example I gave was for the first 4 bytes, as per your question. You then do the same thing for the next 4 bytes, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Here is convertion functions for different data types (your case is unsigned int):

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void endian_swap(unsigned short& x)
{
    x = (x>>8) | 
        (x<<8);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)
{
    x = (x>>24) | 
        ((x<<8) & 0x00FF0000) |
        ((x>>8) & 0x0000FF00) |
        (x<<24);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void endian_swap(unsigned __int64& x)
{
    x = (x>>56) | 
        ((x<<40) & 0x00FF000000000000) |
        ((x<<24) & 0x0000FF0000000000) |
        ((x<<8)  & 0x000000FF00000000) |
        ((x>>8)  & 0x00000000FF000000) |
        ((x>>24) & 0x0000000000FF0000) |
        ((x>>40) & 0x000000000000FF00) |
        (x<<56);
}
```